# To show responsive marker icon on image based on its x,y coordinates in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have to mark the icon on image based on x,y coordinates in angular 4. 
I had done coding for desktop view. its working as expected.
But when i move to mobile and tablet device responsiveness is not working.
please help me to solve this issue.

```
<div class="container col-md-6">
     <img src="https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/n/3cpbpra_1422080.jpg?q=80" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" (mousemove)="getImageCoordinate($event)" (click)="lockTheImageCordinates()" (mouseleave)="resetImageCordinates( )">
 <img style="width:35px;position: absolute !important;" [hidden]="showTheImage" [ngStyle]="setMyStyles()" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Chartreuse.png"id="marker" (click)="getImageData()"/>
```

```
getImageCoordinate(elem) {
   this.xAxis = elem.offsetX;
  this.yAxis = elem.offsetY - 30;
 }
 lockTheImageCordinates() {
   this.xAxisLocked = this.xAxis;
this.yAxisLocked = this.yAxis;
this.showTheImage=false;
 }
setMyStyles() {

    let styles = {
'left':this.xAxisLocked+'px',
'top': this.yAxisLocked+'px'
   };
      return styles; 

}
```

Comment: it's not working as it's not updating like, after resizing your viewport?

Comment: its working in my Desktop View. after resizing to mobile and tablet is not working..My pixel value is changing....

Comment: you have to re-run your function on resize, you could do that with HostListener.

Comment: i have tried it .. its not working as expected..

Comment: Care to provide a plunker or something like that?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-io2ftr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I posted this example in Stack-blitz :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-io2ftr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please help me in resolving this issue.